# Is there an API that allows a candidate search query?

Tags: linkedin-api

We're looking into integrating with LinkedIn so that we can feed our users with lists of job candidates, and then send our users back to LinkedIn in order to view relevant profiles. I'm not seeing any relevant API docs regarding this. Is this something that is possible to do via your API today or in the near future?

Answer (score 0):

Right now, LinkedIn gives only the scope of r_liteprofile and r_emailaddress to Retrieve authenticated member's name, headline, photo, and member's primary email address.

To get the relevant candidate for the job, you may need to check skills, projects, etc, for that you need the permission of r_fullprofile,

LinkedIn API has restricted such information as per their documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/profile/full-profile
[image]

As per their documentation, to access the information of skills, address, etc, your app needs to request r_fullprofile. But they have closed it now and no alternate is given. The more detail about the current permissions from LinkedIn can be seen here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/getting-access

Right now there are currently in development mode. They are working on developing their APIs. What and when they will release such information is not available to document right now.